# How can ul / li have dynamic height?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

This seems like basic CSS knowledge, so it's almost embarrassing to ask.
But why isn't my ul / li scaling when I'm using a large font? I'm using jQuery Mobile, but I don't think that is overriding my css.

[image]

[See my fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ar2dm6h5/).

I've tried using `inline-block`, `height: 100%` on my ul/li - but still get the same results.

```
// HTML
<ui class="stats box-wrapper ui-corner-all">
    <li>
        <div class="number num-stores">7</div>
        <div class="">Stores</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="number num-brands">99</div>
        <div class="">Brands</div>
    </li>
</ui>

// CSS
.box-wrapper{
    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
    border: solid 1px @supp-gray2;
    background-color: #C9DDE0;
    margin: 40px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.number {
    font-size: 3.6em;
}
// More css over at jsFiddle
```

Comment: Remove the line-height. - http://jsfiddle.net/ar2dm6h5/2/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to remove `line-height`.

```
li {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ar2dm6h5/4/

Answer (score 2):

The `line-height` attribute is inherited from `li` to `.number`. Add this:

```
.number {
    line-height: normal;
}
```